# Why is Java crashing on even the simplest Swing program?

Tags: java, swing, crash, jframe

For seemingly no reason, Java has started crashing whenever I try to run anything with Swing. If I run the HelloWorld program, for example, just to test things, it'll run perfectly fine. But if I try to run a program with a JFrame, no matter how simple (I even tried the JFrame demo example on Java's website just so I could get a bare-bones JFrame program), I always get the "Java SE Platform Binary has stopped working" error.

Could this be related to a graphics driver update? I'd think not but you never know.

This is the demo I tried:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
            emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
            frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should always use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` when dealing with Swing from `main()` or from any thread that isn't EDT.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Still I am not allowed to post a comment. That is why I answer even for simple things.

1. Go to Environment variables.
2. Under the System Variables, click on new.
3. In the variable name, enter _JAVA_OPTIONS
4. In the Variable Value, enter -Xmx256M
5. Press OK and Check if it works now.